# How to collect all atrributes of Model including these from Hstore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, metaprogramming, hstore

Right now to collect all attributes names I have to:

```
@attr_names = (User.attribute_names + User.accessible_attributes.to_a - ["", "data"]).uniq
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I am very curious in which situation this would come in handy :)

Comment: I want to generate excel report with dynamically collected all ``User`` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight improvement (assuming `User.attribute_names` and `User.accessible_attributes.to_a` do not each involve a duplicate):

```
@attr_names = (User.attribute_names | User.accessible_attributes.to_a) - ["", "data"]
```